# Routes for connection between two machines through an intermiediate linux device

Tags: linux, networking, windows, ping

I have the following setup:

```
----PC---- 
10.8.0.1/24
```

```
--LINUX1--
10.8.0.6/24
192.168.1.3/24
```

```
--LINUX2--
192.168.1.1/24
```

I want to ping LINUX2 from the PC and vice-versa. What routes do i need to add on the respective devices.

I ran this on Linux1:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And, from what i gather, this should be enough on LINUX1 to route b/w the networks, but I may be wrong about this.

I have added 10.8.0.3 as the default gateway on LINUX2:

```
# route -e
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ath0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 ath0
default         192.168.1.3     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ath0
```

And after that I can ping both interfaces of LINUX1 from LINUX2, but i still cannot ping the PC.

I added a route on the PC to the 192.168.1.0/24 network like so:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.20.1    192.168.20.90     20
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.2         10.8.0.1     30
         10.8.0.0  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.8.0.1    286
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    286
         10.8.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     192.168.126.1    296
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.126.1    276
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.6         10.8.0.1     33
     192.168.20.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.20.90    276
```

But I stll cannot ping LINUX2 from the PC. 
I can ping only the 10.8.0.6 interface of LINUX1 from the PC, but i cannot ping the 192.168.1.3.

If it matters the 10.8.0.0 is an openVPN the 192.168.1.0 is just a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Default gateways aside, you have to tell `PC` that it can reach `LINUX2` (and the complete 192.168.1.* LAN segment) via `LINUX1`:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.6
```

and you have to tell `LINUX2` that it can reach `PC` via `LINUX1`:

```
ip route add 10.0.8.0/24 via 192.168.1.3
```

You already enabled forwarding on `LINUX1`, and the link-local routes should be enough. So now you should be able to `ping 192.168.1.1` from `PC`, and also `ping 10.8.0.1` from `LINUX2`. If it doesn't work, debug with `tcpdump -i interface_name` (with the network interface you want to dump) and `ip route get ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, don't i already have that route set up on the pc with this line that i posted from route print:


  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.6         10.8.0.1     33

But yes I also suspect the PC is not routing correctly, because when i tracert the ip it goes through the default gateway, and not through 10.8.0.6.

Comment: The delete the default gateway (for testing), and see if it works.

Comment: I cannot do that (i tried) on the PC, as it also doubles as the VPN server and that would kill the connection to the remaining devices. When i remove 0.0.0.0 on the PC i lose connection to all VPN clients. I used wireshark to confirm that the problem is indeed in the PC, sending the packets on the wrong interface. No idea how to resolve that though.